# Помогите с изменением XML файла

Tags: php, xml

Есть файл xml на пример с такой структурой:

```
<markers>
   <marker>
      <type></type>
      <title></title>
      <address></address>
      <latitude></latitude>
      <longitude></longitude>
   </marker>
   <marker>
      <type></type>
      <title></title>
      <address></address>
      <latitude></latitude>
      <longitude></longitude>
   </marker>
</markers>
```

Необходимо программно в php изменить структуру файла `xml`. Либо может быть кто то знает софт для данных целей, тогда подскажите софтину.

Конечный файл должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
    <auto>
       <model>
          <type></type>
          <title></title>
       </model>
       <model>
          <type></type>
          <title></title>
       </model>
    </auto>
```

Файлы большие. Изменять нужно много. Хочу хотя бы понять по какому принципу либо в чем это делается.

Comment: Ну вы поискали как работать c xml в php?

Comment: коли слова XML вы уже знаете, ознакомьтесь с аббревиатурой XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже написал в комментарии для преобразований XML документа существует XSLT. В пхп поддерживается на уровне модуля `php_xsl.so`.

В общем случае загружаете 2 документа (исходный и стили) создаете экземпляр `XSLTProcessor` и применяете одно к другому.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('input.xml');    

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('transform.xsl');   

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();  
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);    
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

О самом XSLT я имею весьма поверхностные представления, но например такая таблица стилей

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="markers">
    <auto>
      <xsl:for-each select="marker">
         <model>
           <type><xsl:value-of select="type"/></type>     
         </model>  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </auto>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

сформирует вам желаемый документ. В целом там используются выражения XPath и т.п. Так что почитайте литературу и используйте эти средства. Либо решайте задачу влоб, читая один документ, и формируя на его основе второй.

Если файлы большие прям вообще большие (сотни мегабайт, гигабайты) то решения на основе DOM вам вообще не пойдут, потому что все это будет съедать всю память и падать. В таком случае следует использовать SAX-парсеры и т.п. Либо искать решения, способные потоково читать документ и применять XSL трансформации.

Answer (score -1):

Можешь использовать SimpleXML.
Для ознакомления два сайта:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php
https://shra.ru/2018/06/perevodim-massiv-v-xml-na-php/